# Sprites: Are there any tools to scale sprites individually without using Photoshop/GIMP?

Tags: game-design, textures, sprites, tools, scale

I am using [TexturePacker as tool](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to pack my 2D sprites, it is good but it doesn't provide the possibility to scale individual sprites to a specific scale.

I am wondering whether there is any good tool or command line to scale the files in the original folder without having to use TexturePacker.

What I am trying to do is to fix some scaling errors that the illustrator that produced the files did without having to re-scale/fix things using Photoshop that is more time expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the [ImageMagick Convert Command-Line Tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php):

It is very easy to manipulate images, for example to resize:

```
convert input.png -resize 200% output.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I don't know exactly what the problem is. First if the sprites are small (16x16 or 32x32), you want to use a proper editing tool anyway. At these resolutions scaling will almost always look very ugly.

Now to the solution: [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

ImageMagick is a command line tool and combined with a small shell/batch script you can convert, resize or whatever lots of images in a batch.

Here is the [documentation on resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/)

Here is a [forum thread discussing your program with some example batch scripts](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14587).